# Milliseconds not showing in SQL output for DateTime type

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I am having a problem seeing the millisecond component of a `DATETIME` type column.

The code that defines the table is:

```
string command = string.Format("CREATE TABLE {0}(EventDateTime DATETIME, layer3Id VARCHAR(35), EventType VARCHAR(55), Protocol VARCHAR(30), MessageBody VARCHAR(MAX), MessageContent VARCHAR(MAX))", tableName);
SendSqlCommand(command);
```

The code that populates the row is :

```
string insertCommand = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO {0} VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6)", tablename);

_con.Open();

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertCommand, _con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", record.EventDateTime);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", record.layer3Id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", record.EventType);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", record.Protocol);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", record.MessageBody);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", record.MessageContent);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

where the `EventDateTime` string value is something like `2016/01/09 16:10:08.500`

When I run a query on the table I get back this: `09/01/2016 16:10:08`

No milliseconds. I don't know if the values are going to the database or if it is the wrong type to use or if the query is not responding correctly:

```
TestTable.Take (100)
```

Comment: Well, are there no milliseconds, or are you not SEEING them because the default ToString does not show them? Please use a debugger with a breakpoint to INSPECT the variable. Oh, and post the table definition because it is quite possible you never store them in the database.

Comment: Sql Server DATETIME stores milliseconds (.000-999), so the problem is probably in how you are printing or looking at the results.

Comment: Can you view the underlying table via [SSMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio)?  A DateTime field will hold milliseconds, but they may be set to 000, if `record.EventDateTime` does not support this level of granularity.

Comment: Show us your connection string.

Comment: _When I run a query on the table I get back this.._ `ExecuteNonQuery` does **not** return any `DateTime` or something. It just returns affected row numbers for INSERT, UPDATE etc.. It is _really_ important for us how to see/represent this value to solve your problem.

Comment: Can you show your table datatype declaration as we as how you display your data (which does not show milliseconds)? The problem could be in either case. But `datetime` data type itself should have 0.003 seconds precision and should not lose your milliseconds

Comment: [The `datetime` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277%28SQL.80%29.aspx) only has a precision of approximately 1/300th second. If you need millisecond precision, use [`datetime2(3)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So lets assume you have those values in your database:

[image]

By running pure sql statement you should be able to retrieve datetime in the format you would anticipate, with milliseconds

[image]

And in your C#, as an example, you can control the format, here is an example:

```
            var res = db.MyTables.Take(100);

            foreach(var date in  res)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDateTime(date.EventDateTime).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff"));
            }
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There **are** milliseconds. You just don't display them.

So, when you read the time from the database, you need to format it for output, like this:

```
string s;
s.Format("{0:yyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff}", record.EventDateTime)
```

Now you can display the variable `s`